# CMD option to exit OneDrive

Tags: windows, command-line, onedrive, windows-task-scheduler

I am running OneDrive sync by creating scheduled tasks in Windows Task Scheduler. I have two tasks, one to start OneDrive's desktop app and the other kills it.

I am currently using `taskkill` to get the job done and I am not proud of it. I am looking to see if there is a graceful way to exit/close/stop OneDrive from syncing.

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: What wrong with task kill?

Comment: I am looking for a more graceful way to close it

Answer (score 6):

`OneDrive.exe /shutdown` is what you seek.  Or more formally:

Windows Vista, 7, and 10:

```
cd /d %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive
OneDrive.exe /shutdown
```

Windows 8.1:

```
cd /d %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive
OneDrive.exe /shutdown
```

NOTE: To restart OneDrive from a batch file, you will need to use the "start" command.  Running the .exe directly will leave the batch file open "forever".

Answer (score 0):

Find where OneDrive.exe is, as the above didn't work for me.

(Windows 10 instructions)

i. Select Start (Windows icon) or the Search icon
ii. Type "OneDrive"
iii. Right-click OneDrive and select `Open file location`
-- This brings you to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
iv. Right-click on the OneDrive.exe file and select `Open file location`
-- This brings you to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive`
-- This is where the OneDrive.exe file is

Create a bat file with this

`cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive" && OneDrive.exe /shutdown && exit`

Edit the part "`C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive`" to where the OneDrive.exe file is for you, if it's not in this location.